# Axapta 2009 database log report error

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

While generating Db log report in production with several table id's as parameter and createdDateTime > 8-Aug-2016. I am getting the below error.

`Cannot create a record in Print job information (page-level) (PrintJobPages). pageNo: 1. The record already exists.`

As the issue is in PROD i cannot restart services/AOS. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use the [Print Archive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg231521.aspx)?
If you do, try to disable it.

This could be `RecId` generation error, if there are records in the `PrintJobPages` table with id higher than new generated ids.

This may be corrected be setting the next record id to a higher value in the `SystemSequences` system table (using SQL Enterprise Manager). See [this](http://deepakdyanmicsax.blogspot.dk/2014/03/record-ids-in-ax-2012_5.html) and [that blog](http://mybhat.blogspot.dk/2012/11/misleading-record-already-exists-message.html).

Comment: Thank you. !'m not using Print Archive. Inmy case the 'Max(RecId)` table id for table is less than `nextVal` field in `SystemSequences`. Can there be any other cause?

Comment: Check the indexes of the table.

Comment: There is an index PKIdx on (Recid, RefrecId, Empld, and two more fields). I have made a change in the batchJob parameter. Old batchJob was working fine. Now even the db log report is throwing error with "that" tableId.

Comment: Yes it is. Index property `AllowDuplicates` is set as `No`.

Comment: Then consider whether this could be the reason. Or disable the index then synchronise the table.

Comment: But the only question remains... If that's the case then how come it was working fine so far?

Comment: As you have provided no details of your customisation an answer would be purely speculative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120623/discussion-between-piku-and-jan-b-kjeldsen).

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error when modifying the SalesInvoice report in DAX 2009. In our test environment, of course. I tried everything above, but nothing worked. A backup version of the report worked, so I started backing out some custimizations one at a time.

I realized I had commented out a VAR customization in the fetch method, similar to this line of code. I uncommented and this worked.

```
this.footerEnable(totals,                   showFooter && !taxPrintTaxFreeBalance);
```